# Programming languages for genetic engineering

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, bioinformatics, research

I'm interested in getting a Ph.D. and would love to work on a project such the [GEC project at Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gec/), which studies the application of programming languages for synthetic biology and genetic engineering. What groups are doing work like this in a university setting?

Comment: The web page you mention answers your question by listing four academics (one in Edinburgh, three in Cambridge) working on the project... Also, check out the papers listed to see if any of their authors are in academia.

Answer (score 1):

I choose to reply in an answer rather than a comment because I think
that is actually the proper answer to your question (and it is too
long for a comment anyway).

1. Style

   If you intend to do research and write papers for an audience, then
   you should learn to be easy to read. Any improvement costs only once
   to you, and saves time and energy to each one of your readers. That
   includes giving web references that  can be clicked, rather than
   having to be cut and pasted in a browser window. That also include
   briefly telling your readers what the reference is about, so that
   they do not have to jump into unknown territory. (this is a comment on
   [the original version of your question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/28560/1), before the [friendly editing of
   David Richerby](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/28560/revisions)).

   The same is actually true for programs. It is not enough to write a
   program that solves the problem, you should also make sure that it is
   easy to understand and to use, so as to spare aggravation to your
   users.
2. Substance

   Getting a Ph.D entails doing a fair amount of research. The very
   first step is to find litterature that is relevant to your research
   topic. Usually, if you choose the topic, you are supposed to have
   some knowledge of it. In your case, you know of a project that is
   relevant.  So that gives you names, keywords, and topics to search for on the
   web. Then some reading of that should give you a better
   understanding, increase your competence and allow you to search for
   more ... and find research groups that do that kind of work by
   looking at the authors of papers. Their affiliation is usually given,
   and many have a web site.

   Doing this yourself will increase you general competence at doing
   research, and also increase your knowledge of the field. It is in no
   way wasted work. Doing if for you is not doing you a service. You
   would not think of getting someone on the net to write your
   dissertation for you. Of course, it does make sense to discuss issues
   and ask questions, but usually after doing what work you can, so as
   to spare the time of colleagues ... they do not have so much available.

   But if you cannot do it yourself, you probably do not have the
   maturity to do research and you should rather consider another
   academic path, or professional path.

Comment: While you may give some good advice, how does this answer the question? One comment: unfortunately, being "easy to read" tends to be unappreciated in some communities. :/

Comment: @Raphael I agree that this isn't an answer but an extended comment. The paragraph beginning "Getting a Ph.D" is highly relevant as a comment to this question but it mostly repeats my own comment; the rest is generic advice.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I said myself that it may be perceived as a comment, but that I do
consider it an answer. If the question had been only: "What groups are
doing work like xxx in a university setting?", then you would
certainly be right. Motivation would be none of my business. But the
question was asked in a context, and thus this context is part of the
question and can orient the answer. Or, to take another angle, why
didn't you give a straight answer to [this
question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28576)? Hopefully, we
all do what we think we ought to do. No problem.